# Is it possible to return different table variables through SQL Server table valued function based on param value passed in it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written some set of statements which returns a table with some static columns. But I'll required to download csv format using the same function with different column. (Reason is that I created static columns to display high charts and we are using custom code to export chart data so require some different format to download)
In table valued function, I dont know how to return the Dynamic columns of the table based on pram passed to function.
How to write the table value function for this scenario? If this is not possible then what would be the alternative for this task(Stored procedure can't be used in my existing scnerio due to some limitation of code)? 
Any suggestions please.

Comment: Build SQL dynamically as a string and execute that

Comment: try to write a minimal example statement, you must make our work easy :)